# "Fail Render" Javascript files and Css

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, angularjs

I have a *strange* issue when trying to load some JS and CSS files.

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web Project and inside it I have `Index.html` and ask to load some script files. I believe it is important to mention that I rewrited the URL in `Web.config` so instead of showing me something like : `localhost:2064/Index.html` to show `localhost:2064/` or `localhost:2064/Index/`.

I use the normal "call" for my scripts like:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js" ></script>
<script src="Scripts/Layout/menu.js" ></script>
```

But, in console I get some errors (Chrome Inspector Console):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :2064/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :2064/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :2064/Scripts/bootstrap.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < modernizr-2.6.2.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < menu.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < app.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < indexController.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < homeController.js:1
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=PBA&p1=Error%3A%20%…F1.2.6%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DPBA%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native...<omitted>...4) MINERR_ASSET:22
```

When I inspected to see the content of those files I get the following info:

**STATUS:** 304 Not Modified

**CONTENT:** Same as my HTML file (not as expected).

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your rewrite logic is wrong.

If you analyze your errors you will see that each javascript file has a '<' character on the first line. That indicates to me that you are probably serving one of your html files instead of the actual javascript files.

Also make sure you are serving each file with a proper content type, ie 'text/javascript', 'text/html', etc.

Comment: It's because your rewrite logic is broken. Post your rewrite logic here so that we can help.